# Expandable and Collapsable TableViewCells

Tags: swift, uitableview, swift5

**I am trying to do the following logic: if cell1 is tapped, it should expand its height. Then, if cell2 is tapped, it should expand its height and return cell1 to its original height so that only one cell can be expanded.**

**This is my current code but it expands all the cells and is not doing what I want:**

```
@IBOutlet weak var poemasTableView: UITableView!
var isExpanded = true

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        
        if isExpanded == true {
            return 55
        } else {
            return 240
        }
    }
```

**My TableViewCell has a button which I am adding this function:**

```
@objc func cambiarTamaño() {
        poemasTableView.beginUpdates()
        isExpanded = !isExpanded
        poemasTableView.endUpdates()
    }
```

**How could i fix this?**

Comment: Your logic will either expand all cells or will collapse all cells at a time, you need to save the index path of cell tapped and use that indexpath in condition to expand or collapse specific cell

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep track of which cell is selected, then in `heightForRowAt` check to see if that cell is the selected one.

```
var selected: IndexPath?

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if indexPath.row == selected?.row {
        return 240
    } else {
        return 55
    }
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if selected == indexPath {
        selected = nil
    } else {
        selected = indexPath
    }
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Looks like you want to use a button in the table view cell to do this, so you will need to pass in the `indexPath` into the cell, then when that button is pressed, pass the `indexPath` back to the table view class to update the `selected` variable.

Comment: How would i do this?